# MS Access / SQL : error in insert query statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am using MS Access 1997 version (`.mdb` file). On a daily basis, I need to insert values manually. In that file, there's a column `Logical` (Boolean data type). I am automate this template using SQL query instead of direct entry.

Below is my insert query:

```
Insert Into Data_CustomerTransmit_Tbl (Logical) 
Values (" & Logicalnme & ")
```

Values:

```
Logicalnme - True
```

When I run this query in VBA in Excel, I get this error message

> Syntax Error in Insert into Statement

Kindly confirm shall I use "Logical" as column name or this is the reserved keyword?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Logical is fine, its the insert value that you should look at.

Comment: Change the name of the attribute and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for your response. I am unable to change database filed and table name . It is a predefined. Kindly Confirm is there any possible we have. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this query going ? `Insert Into Data_CustomerTransmit_Tbl (Logical)  Values (1)`

Comment: Yes this query need to insert one field only. Table name - Data_CustomerTransmit_Tbl, Field name - Logical. Datatype - boolean. Value- True.

Comment: Access actually uses -1 for true, not 1.

Comment: Why this string expression {" & Logicalnme & "} for Boolean field.

Comment: Try with `Values (" & Logicalname & ")`. No one would label a variable _Logicalnme_ ...

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a problem with your field name, you just need to enclose your `INSERT` column name in square brackets. You also need to choose a valid value in the `VALUES` clause:

```
INSERT INTO Data_CustomerTransmit_Tbl ( [Logical] )
VALUES (TRUE);
```

If you want to be prompted for the value to insert, you can use a parameter:

```
PARAMETERS [Please enter a Boolean value] YesNo;
INSERT INTO Data_CustomerTransmit_Tbl ( [Logical] )
VALUES ([Please enter a Boolean value]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are trying to do this insert using VBA? If so, your syntax in building the SQL statement is correct, except you have some punctuation missing:  double-quotes on each end.

```
    "INSERT INTO Data_CustomerTransmit_Tbl (Logical) VALUES (" & Logicalnme & ")"
```

Further, as you have split the string over two lines (breaking before VALUES), you must also terminate the first line of the string with: ' " & _' (space,double-quote,space, ampersand, space, underscore) in order to indicate that the string continues to the next line.  Then  you begin the next line with double-quotes:

```
    "INSERT INTO Data_CustomerTransmit_Tbl (Logical) " & _  
    "VALUES (" & Logicalnme & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

In VBA the code should look like this:

```
Docmd.RunSQL("INSERT INTO Data_CustomerTransmit_Tbl (Logical) VALUES (" & Logicalnme & ");"
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query you alluded to - have you tried to execute it manually in the query editor using the same value(s) you are trying to pass from Excel? That would immediately provide more verbose feedback if there is an issue with the query or the data.

Regarding the Boolean field, make sure you are receiving a True/False that you are expecting, not a bit field, 0 and 1. I like to make quick log entries in a table or a file when troubleshooting to see the raw data.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cbool function:

```
Insert Into Data_CustomerTransmit_Tbl (Logical) 
Values (" & Cbool(Logicalnme) & ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add single quotes around values?

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Data_CustomerTransmit_Tbl (Logical) " & _  
      "VALUES ('" & Logicalnme & "')"
docmd.runsql sql
```